# Simple example using done and setTimeout inside a mocha test not working as expected

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I have a simple test with an assertion contained in a setTimeout function as follows:

```
  it('asserts after timeout', (done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(1).to.be.equal(1);
      done();
    }, 500);
  });
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: May be you need a try catch and put done() inside catch.. The timeout of 2000 may be for the entire page/app..

Answer (score 2):

After banging my head around and looking at every unit test in the code base, I realized there was a call to sinon.useFakeTimers(); Removing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work. However you'll get that error when the expectation fails. For this, wrap your `setTimeout` in a `Promise` and ensure that you call `done` in the next then method.

It's considered `bad practice` because of this to put the `done` method in the same area as what you're testing.

```
it('asserts after timeout', (done) => {
    (new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       setTimeout(() => {
         resolve();
       }, 500);
    }))
    .then(()=>expect(1).to.be.equal(1))
    .then(()=>done(), done);
});
```